# Updating one table with edited data in another - phpmyadmin - can't find field errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been reading and trying just about everything I have come across to solve my problem.  I have a database table I need to update using the values in an "edited" **clone** of the original.

I first tried to "update" the table but discovered the updates added entries to the table not edit what was already there. I have considered manual edits but there are simply too many...I have tried every conceivable combination of setting in phpmyadmin import...

The scenario:  On a shared host, using phpmyadmin.  Table name = mailstudio table I want to update = leads.  Table with the updated/edited values = clean_leads

Table needing updates applied: jd_leads
There are nearly 100 columns so I'll just abbreviate here:

```
1   id  int(11)                No   None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
2   owner_id    int(11)        Yes  NULL            
3   is_published    tinyint(1) No   None         
4   date_added  datetime       Yes  NULL
```

Table ( clean_leads )with the edited information I need to get into the leads table.

```
1   "id"            varchar(7)  utf8_general_ci     No          
2   "owner_id"      varchar(10) utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL            
3   "is_published"  varchar(3)  utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL        
4   "date_added"    varchar(21) utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL
```

SQL Query I am trying to run.

```
UPDATE jd_leads
INNER JOIN clean_leads ON jd_leads.is_published = clean_leads.is_published
SET jd_leads.id=IF(clean_leads.id > 0, clean_leads.id, jd_leads.id)
WHERE clean_leads.id > is_published=0
```

This format seems like it should work but it throws these errors:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'clean_leads.id' in 'field list' AND

## 1146 - Table 'proje485_mailstu.jd_leads' doesn't exist

I have also tried to reverse the logic and get the unedited data into a new table and all I get is the same errors except the error is jd_leads.id does not exist.

I have read just about every thread I can find on these errors yet this nube is unable to figure it out.  I've been at it for a couple of days now and am very frustrated.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank, you,

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax is always:

```
update some_table set some_column = some_value where some_condition;
```

If you want to join something, you'll need to add a FROM clause. In your case:

```
UPDATE jd
SET jd.id=IF(cl.id > 0, cl.id, jd.id)
FROM
    jd_leads jd
    INNER JOIN clean_leads cl ON jd.is_published = cl.is_published

WHERE cl.id > jd.is_published=0 **(make sure to check this line here, because I don't know what table you referred)**
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something funky with that last line:

```
UPDATE jd_leads
INNER JOIN clean_leads ON jd_leads.is_published = clean_leads.is_published
SET jd_leads.id=IF(clean_leads.id > 0, clean_leads.id, jd_leads.id)
WHERE clean_leads.id > 0
AND jd_leads.is_published=0 /* Split from the line above */
```